# How to run tensor flow model locally into Mac

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have ML model deployed in Sagemaker. I copied the model ( tar.gz) to my Mac and trying to write the run that tar.gz model file locally . I need to pass input as an image which will go through this model and provide me output locally.How to write the python code to run this full setup locally.

Comment: what kind of ML model are you using ? any thing can be 'tar.gz', did u untar the item ?

Comment: Sagemaker is for deploying the models in to cloud, and you are asking to run it locally what you actually want to do ?

Comment: Sagemake is deploying model into cloud but we can deploy the model locally as well to save the time to send all images to be processed on cloud. we are trying to call it locally and process images and only processed images will be going to save on cloud. Tensor flow model we are using.I did untar that it is having export folder in that.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use the SageMaker Python SDK's Local Mode feature:

```py
from sagemaker.tensorflow.serving import Model

model = Model(
    model_data='s3://bucket/path/to/your/model',
    ...  # fill in your other params
)

predictor = model.deploy(1, 'local')
predictor.predict(your_data)
```

More info: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#local-mode

If you would rather not use SageMaker's Local Mode, you can find the general TF Serving documentation at https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving.